# CSS styling A href inside <li>

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have menu like that

```
  <ul id="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-selected">
        <a href="/Results">Results</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I want to make menu item selected after it was clicked. I set `li` class `"menu-selected"`
But no luck.

```
.menu-selected ul#menu li a  //also i was trying to say a:link but no luck
 {
    background-color: #91c05e !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ul#menu li.menu-selected a
```

is what you want to do

Comment: Also don't forget to drop the `!important` tags as by then you probably won't need them anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure you want

```
ul li.menu-selected a
```

instead, since that applies to all links inside `<li>` elements with class `menu-selected`.

Answer (score 1):

do:

```
ul#menu li.menu-selected a
```

From left to right it's parent -> child element

You probably only need `.menu-selected a`